# Create new column with means by group

Tags: python, pandas

```
             A    B  C  D
0   2002-01-13  200  X  1
1   2002-01-13  180  X  0
2   2002-01-13  250  X -1
3   2002-01-13  300  Y  1
4   2002-01-13  220  Y  0
5   2002-01-13  125  Y -1
6   2002-02-09  410  X  1
7   2002-02-09    0  X  1
8   2002-02-09  550  Y  1
9   2002-02-09  500  Y  1
10  2002-02-09  150  Y -1
```

I want to create a new `E` column with next conditions, per each `A` group:

- `E` value will be `B` mean values where `D=0` (in 2002-01-13 `A` group, `E` value will be mean between 180 and 220, that´s to say 200).
- If `D=0` doesn´t exist, E value will be mean between: 
  `B` values mean when `C=X`, and `B` values mean when `C=Y`, always excluding `B` zeros (in 2002-02-09 `A` group, `D=0` doesn´t exist. So `E` value will be mean between 410 and 400, that´s to say 405).

Output should be:

```
             A    B  C  D    E
0   2002-01-13  200  X  1  200
1   2002-01-13  180  X  0  200
2   2002-01-13  250  X -1  200
3   2002-01-13  300  Y  1  200
4   2002-01-13  220  Y  0  200
5   2002-01-13  125  Y -1  200
6   2002-02-09  410  X  1  405
7   2002-02-09    0  X  1  405
8   2002-02-09  550  Y  1  405
9   2002-02-09  500  Y  1  405
10  2002-02-09  150  Y -1  405
```

Comment: Try using `groupby()` and `transform()` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: df['E'] = df['A'].map(df.groupby('A').B.mean())

Comment: why For 2002-02-09, when C=Y, mean is 400 ?

Comment: Sorry. Edited right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `groupby` + `np.where`

```
df.A.map(df.assign(B=df.B.replace(0,np.nan)).groupby('A').apply(lambda x : np.where((x['D']==0.0).any(),x['B'][x['D']==0].mean() , x.groupby('C')['B'].mean().mean())))
Out[1615]: 
0     200.0
1     200.0
2     200.0
3     200.0
4     200.0
      ...  
6     405.0
7     405.0
8     405.0
9     405.0
10    405.0
Name: A, Length: 11, dtype: object
#df['E']= df.A.map(df.assign(B=df.B.replace(0,np.nan)).groupby('A').apply(lambda x : np.where((x['D']==0.0).any(),x['B'][x['D']==0].mean() , x.groupby('C')['B'].mean().mean())))
```